# Access - Call on click out of Combobox

Tags: ms-access

I've currently got a Form in a 2007 Access Database with a ComboBox where, unless the dropdown is clicked, I don't want it to have focus. This works most of the time, where a user clicks the dropdown and then selects a row, it'll call the `AfterUpdate` Event, and so I can just change focus through that.

However, my problem is, that when the user opens the ComboBox, doesn't select anything, and clicks to leave. The Dropdown list disappears, but the ComboBox still has focus.

I'm wondering if there's any Event that I'm missing that'll cover this, or any workaround to get this working.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the event on the form Detail section. Something like

```
Private Sub Detail_MouseDown(Button As Integer, Shift As Integer, X As Single, Y As Single)
    Me.WhereverYouWant.SetFocus
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. That was kind of what I was going on. I needed a few more events from elsewhere (heading, footer, etc.) and instead of writing `Me.<Control>.SetFocus` I first checked that the dropdown was the active control, then kind of ran off that.  It's not perfect, if you click the arrow again, it still doesn't work. I've been trying to fix it, but my solutions seem to cause Access to crash then restart itself, so I'll probably leave it there. Thanks again.

Comment: I don't understand why it wouldn't work based on what you said. I have created the environment and it worked just fine. As for access crashing, are you sure there isn't another event on the form that is being fired at the same time. It seem as if there is some conflict somewhere.